AVPlayer's control visibility change event?
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let videoURL: URL
    
    @State private var player: AVPlayer?
    // how to set it true/false based on AVPlayer controls visiblity?
    @State private var controlsAreVisible = true
    @State private var title = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let player = player {
                VideoPlayer(player: player)
                    .onAppear {
                        player.play()
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        player.pause()
                    }
            } else {
                Text("Failed to load video")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        }
        .onDisappear {
            player = nil
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(!controlsAreVisible)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onChange(of: controlsAreVisible) { newValue in
            if (newValue) {
                title = videoURL.lastPathComponent
            } else {
                title = ""
            }
        }
    }
}

So video player screen should be fullscreen, to exit this screen to the previous screen of the app is not a problem for newer iPhones with swipe gesture navigation, but older iPhones like 6s/7 don't have, so still need to show bar back button at least when AVPlayer's controls are visible, but how to detect if there are visible or not?

State is just for values, I doubt you can hold a player object in it

Nothing wrong with using @State private var player: AVPlayer?
See Apple example VideoPlayer
I would simply use @State private var player = AVPlayer() to avoid unwrapping the Optional.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Using the AVPlayer reference type as a state is possible, but not using it as an optional property would be wrong, the solution from the OP is correct. The Apple sample contains incorrect code. Not using an optional property and not creating the instance in onAppear would result in the AVPlayer instance being instantiated each time the view is instantiated. See here

@user924 note that hiding the navigation back bar button with navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) disables the system's edge swipe gesture to navigate back on all iOS versions. So your approach is not just a problem with older iOS versions. You could use a custom video overlay to show your own control element to navigate back.

@ITGuy, yes, I see that having a default Player could consume some extra nanoseconds of CPU.
Similarly, the onAppear can be called many times, and definitely called every time
the View is instantiated. The docs link, recommends using .task....
